# Tags different size depending on usage

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP application and a mysql database, which are working very well. 
In my application you can save a connection between a tag and a ticket. 
It's a n-m entity. 
You can put many tags to a ticket and a ticket can have many tags.

Now I want to print out a list of all tags and mark the tags which are more often used bigger then the others ( font-size).

Basically I've already done this, but I have really no clue how to do this nice and smoothly.

```
String xxx="";
for (TBean tb : tagsList)
    {
        int fontSize = 11;
        fontSize = fontSize + tb.counter; //counter = number of usages
        if (fontSize > 20)
        {
            fontSize = 20;
        }
        xxx += "<span style='font-size:" + fontSize + "px;'>" + tb.name + "</span>";
    } 
return xxx;
```

Comment: If you code works, your question is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

What does tb.counter return? Can its value be negative? If not then your else will never work because fontSize will never be less than 10.

And isn't there a value between 10 and 20?

Anyways you could do something like this

```
fontSize = fontSize>20?20:fontSize<10?10:fontSize
```

Comment: I've edited my code above. But In my mind I'm thinking about when there are a lot of usage of every tag. All tags are displayed in font size 20.

Comment: what exactly do you wish to implement?

Comment: The size of the tags should be evalated by the total amout of all tags.

Comment: am i getting you right here ? there is more than single instance of similar tags  in your tagsList and the tags frequency should determine its type